# Execute a Managed Package's custom button Javascript logic

Tags: custom-button

We have a managed package that contains a custom button. This button currently sits on the Campaign's standard page layout. We would like to check that all the Campaign members meet certain criteria before the javascript of the managed package's custom button executes.

I'm not sure how to approach this, and I didn't want to copy and paste the managed code to my own custom button. Is it possible to execute the code of the managed package's custom button from a different custom button?

Comment: You might be able to replace the custom button with your own if the method being called inside of the managed package was global.

Comment: can you see the code for the javascript in the managed package's custom button?

Answer (score 1):

With a little bit of dev work you should be able to build a custom button that evaluates your criteria and if it passes calls the managed package button.

You could place the logic in javascript with a custom button, or create a visualforce page that is tied to a custom button with an apex controller to evaluate your entry criteria.

If it passes you'll want to use URLFOR to call the managed package button with the campaign id. E.g. `{!URLFOR($Action.Campaign.Button_Name,Campaign.Id)}`.  If it doesn't you'll want to provide some feedback to the end user about why the button didn't process.

#### Example JS

```
var goodToGo = true;
// logic to determine if it's good to go
if(goodToGo) {
  window.location.href = '{!URLFOR($Action.Account.APXTConga4__Conga_Mail_Merge,Account.Id)}'
alert(url);
} else {
  alert('Not ready to go');
}
```

#### Example Button

[image]

Comment: I can see the JavaScript code in the Managed Package's custom button. I'm creating my own custom button that will execute javascript to perform checks using SF's Ajax Toolkit. Can you give an example of how I would use "{!URLFOR($Action.Campaign.Button_Name,Campaign.Id)}" in a JS command?  It's not doing anything when I use it by itself.

Comment: yep, that returns the URL, it doesn't do anything else, you'd need to change the window location with it, e.g. `window.top.location.href = '{!URLFOR(...)}';`.  If you're doing this you should either (A) be comfortable with JS, (B) be okay with a lot of trial and error and head scratching when you're stuff works fine in one browser but not another.

Comment: Using the `window.top.location.href` does not seem to allow access to the JS code of the button. The result is a page with the error 'URL No Longer Exists'. I've tried manipulating the returned URL to see if there's a URL format issue, but that hasn't brought in the JS either.

Comment: you don't need to bring in the JS, just execute yours then refer the page to their button which will cause their js to get executed, i've updated the answer

Comment: idea is that if there js changes you don't have to update your code, in essence you need to think of their button as a black box, you don't know what's inside, you just know that if certain conditions are met you open the black box, otherwise you tell the user you aren't opening the box

Comment: I am finding that referencing the $Action like this works when the referenced button’s Content Source is 'URL' and 'Standard Salesforce.com Page'. However, when the Content Source is 'OnClick Javascript' the code reference does not execute the other button's code. Which is how the managed package's button is configured. I understand the concept and appreciate the elaboration. I had not known it was possible to make references like these before.

Comment: so that test, uses a button that's in a managed package and executes javascript, works fine for me.  Your code just redirects to the other one, which then executes it's own javascript, guess I'm not following your issue.

Comment: My custom button with behavior 'Execute JavaScript' runs the command `window.location.href = '{!URLFOR($Action.Campaign.The_Manged_Package_Button,Campaign.Id)}';`. The result is an error page that says 'URL No Longer Exists', and the managed package button's JavaScript is not run. The URL pulled in with the $Action variable does contain the 15 position identifier of the custom button, so I think the $Action variable is correct. Maybe what I'm trying to do isn't possible. I've experimented with many variations of this in my company and personal org.

Comment: that's pretty strange, perhaps post that as another question? e.g. why does the url returned by urlfor give me a url no longer exist error message? based on my testing, it's possible, but sounds like it has some gotchas to work through